# I need help getting an outside url to display as if it is part of my site

Tags: wordpress, hosting, url-masking

I have a client who's site is hosted by siteground and is built with wordpress. He had another company develop a virtual tour site that is being hosted on digital ocean by the developers. I am trying to make it so when you visit "clientsWebsite.com/virtualtour" it will display the actual virtual tour but still display his site in the url bar.

I have attempted to add a subdomain i.e. "virtualtour.clientswebsite.com" but this does not seem to work, the client also would prefer it to display as "clientswebsite.com/virtualtour". Fellow devs have informed me to look into url forwarding/masking but have been unable to find useful or detailed information on the subject.

The code below is the only thing I have been able to find but the instructions for this leave much unanswered.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Description">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2">
    </head>
    <body>
        <frameset rows="100%,0" border="0">
        <frame src="http://yourotherdomain.com" frameborder="0">
        <frame frameborder="0">
        </frameset>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am able to link to the virtual tour but it displays the original url which is unappealing and unrelated to the clients website

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making a page in wordpress with this code ?

Domain - clientsWebsite.com Pagename - virtualtour

```
<iframe src="http://virtualtour.clientswebsite.com" name="virtualtour" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

You can visit this by http://clientsWebsite.com/virtualtour

(make sure the frame and main website both have to be either with SSL or both without SSL)